# How to measure uncertainty and prediction errors for a naive Bayesian Classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, naive-bayes-classifier

I have a small dataset of 30 rows and 5 columns (4 features and 1 class). The classifier is used to give the likelihood of occurrence of an incident. thus, the class variable gives the probability of occurrence.

How can I measure the **uncertainty** and **prediction errors** of my classifier?

I have read a post [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/35861/how-to-measure-the-uncertainty-of-prediction) about measuring the **uncertainty** of prediction. However, it is tacking the issue of multiclass classification!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the probability returned by your model. Just be aware that probability is not uncertainty but if you [calibrate your probabilities](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.calibration_curve.html#sklearn.calibration.calibration_curve), you can have an idea of the belief of event realisation from a frequentist point of view.

For the error of prediction, with a calibrated classifier if you have a probability of 0.8 to belong to a certain class, you can expect that there is a 80% chance that your sample actually belongs to this class.